# executing the opencv3-python file

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, virtualenv, opencv3.0, virtualenvwrapper

I have installed opencv3 and python 2.7 in ubuntu.So everytime i have to run the python code,i have to execute a set of commands in the terminal:

```
     $ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
     $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
     $ source ~/.bashrc
```

and then,

```
     $ workon cv
```

only then can i run the python file.If i type workon cv without those three commands,i get an error saying,workon command not found. So,i have two questions, firstly, is there any method where i needn't have to do the whole process of exporting the virtualenv everytime before i give workon cv?

The other purpose of this question,
What if i have to make my opencv-python code an application? How would i resolve this issue of export this virtualenvs everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the first two commands to the end of your `.bashrc` file

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

now start a new terminal and you are good to go